# Create groups based on at least one common characteristic

Tags: r

I have the first two columns of data in the following format. I would like to generate the third column according to the following rule: Each group will consist of all Rep values that correspond to at least one common Tran value. In the example, you can see that A and B are linked by 3, B and C by 5, etc.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Rep</th><th>Tran</th><th>Group</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>6</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>7</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>D</td><td>10</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>D</td><td>9</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>D</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>E</td><td>11</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>E</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>E</td><td>65</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>E</td><td>78</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>F</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>F</td><td>11</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>F</td><td>33</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>G</td><td>450</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>G</td><td>22</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I also have the same data in wide format, though I suspect that will be less conducive to efficient code at this point.

I'd like to solve this using R, but have been really spinning my wheels.

Comment: what do you mean by `linked by` ? Groups have common Tran values ?  How are other groups related ? Please explain more.

Comment: My apologies. Let me provide some further clarification.

REP values are themselves aggregates of TRAN values. For example, the Tran values 1,2,3 roll up into the REP value A. 

I would like to create groups which group together all REP values that share at least one component TRAN value. For example, the TRAN value 3 is a component of both A and B, so all rows where REP is A or B would be in the same group.